Failed to build grpcio grpcio-tools, Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (grpcio, grpcio-tools)
Manually running pip install grpcio and pip install grpcio-tools is successful.
However, running 'pip install -r requirements.txt', where requirements.txt is
grpcio==1.62.2
grpcio-tools==1.62.2

gives the following error (the full error is too long, I am only attaching the bottom portion):
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include" "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\AIINTE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp12fy4pjb\a.c /Fo\Users\AIINTE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp12fy4pjb\a.obj
      a.c
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 70, in spawn
          subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=_inject_macos_ver(env))
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\subprocess.py", line 419, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe', '/c', '/nologo', '/O2', '/W3', '/GL', '/DNDEBUG', '/MD', '-D_WIN32_WINNT=1536', '-DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX="\\"Python\\""', '-DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX="\\"1.62.2\\""', '-DOPENSSL_NO_ASM=1', '-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1', '-DCARES_STATICLIB=1', '-DGRPC_ARES=0', '-DNTDDI_VERSION=100663296', '-DNOMINMAX=1', '-DMS_WIN64=1', '-DGRPC_DO_NOT_INSTANTIATE_POSIX_POLLER=1', '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS', '-Isrc\\python\\grpcio', '-Iinclude', '-I.', '-Ithird_party\\abseil-cpp', '-Ithird_party\\address_sorting\\include', '-Ithird_party\\cares\\cares\\include', '-Ithird_party\\cares', '-Ithird_party\\cares\\cares', '-Ithird_party\\re2', '-Ithird_party\\boringssl-with-bazel\\src\\include', '-Ithird_party\\upb', '-Isrc\\core\\ext\\upb-gen', '-Isrc\\core\\ext\\upbdefs-gen', '-Ithird_party\\utf8_range', '-Ithird_party\\xxhash', '-Ithird_party\\zlib', '-IC:\\Users\\AI Internist\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\AI Internist\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\Include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\ATLMFC\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\ucrt', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\um', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\shared', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\winrt', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\cppwinrt', '/EHsc', '/Tcsrc/core/ext/upb-gen/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.upb_minitable.c', '/Fopyb\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\\Release\\src/core/ext/upb-gen/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.upb_minitable.obj', '/std:c11', '/MT']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 455, in compile
          self.spawn(args)
          ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 553, in spawn
          return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ux0bxp6b\grpcio_1c3f47c8b7304b1ab2167cd92f78c99e\src\python\grpcio\_spawn_patch.py", line 58, in _commandfile_spawn
          _classic_spawn(self, command, **kwargs)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1045, in spawn
          spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
          ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 76, in spawn
          raise DistutilsExecError(
              f"command {_debug(cmd)!r} failed with exit code {err.returncode}"
          ) from err
      distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ux0bxp6b\grpcio_1c3f47c8b7304b1ab2167cd92f78c99e\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 313, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 264, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 557, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
              sources,
          ...<5 lines>...
              depends=ext.depends,
          )
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 457, in compile
          raise CompileError(msg)
      distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                              metadata_directory)
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 438, in build_wheel
          return _build(['bdist_wheel', '--dist-info-dir', str(metadata_directory)])
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 426, in _build
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
              cmd,
              ^^^^
          ...<3 lines>...
              self._arbitrary_args(config_settings),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          )
          ^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 407, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
.
.
.
.
.
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 70, in spawn
          subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=_inject_macos_ver(env))
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\subprocess.py", line 419, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe', '/c', '/nologo', '/O2', '/W3', '/GL', '/DNDEBUG', '/MD', '-D_WIN32_WINNT=1536', '-DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX="\\"Python\\""', '-DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX="\\"1.62.2\\""', '-DOPENSSL_NO_ASM=1', '-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1', '-DCARES_STATICLIB=1', '-DGRPC_ARES=0', '-DNTDDI_VERSION=100663296', '-DNOMINMAX=1', '-DMS_WIN64=1', '-DGRPC_DO_NOT_INSTANTIATE_POSIX_POLLER=1', '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS', '-Isrc\\python\\grpcio', '-Iinclude', '-I.', '-Ithird_party\\abseil-cpp', '-Ithird_party\\address_sorting\\include', '-Ithird_party\\cares\\cares\\include', '-Ithird_party\\cares', '-Ithird_party\\cares\\cares', '-Ithird_party\\re2', '-Ithird_party\\boringssl-with-bazel\\src\\include', '-Ithird_party\\upb', '-Isrc\\core\\ext\\upb-gen', '-Isrc\\core\\ext\\upbdefs-gen', '-Ithird_party\\utf8_range', '-Ithird_party\\xxhash', '-Ithird_party\\zlib', '-IC:\\Users\\AI Internist\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\AI Internist\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\Include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\ATLMFC\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\ucrt', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\um', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\shared', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\winrt', '-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\\\include\\10.0.22621.0\\\\cppwinrt', '/EHsc', '/Tcsrc/core/ext/upb-gen/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.upb_minitable.c', '/Fopyb\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\\Release\\src/core/ext/upb-gen/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.upb_minitable.obj', '/std:c11', '/MT']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 455, in compile
          self.spawn(args)
          ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 553, in spawn
          return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ux0bxp6b\grpcio_1c3f47c8b7304b1ab2167cd92f78c99e\src\python\grpcio\_spawn_patch.py", line 58, in _commandfile_spawn
          _classic_spawn(self, command, **kwargs)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1045, in spawn
          spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
          ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 76, in spawn
          raise DistutilsExecError(
              f"command {_debug(cmd)!r} failed with exit code {err.returncode}"
          ) from err
      distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ux0bxp6b\grpcio_1c3f47c8b7304b1ab2167cd92f78c99e\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 313, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 264, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 557, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
              sources,
          ...<5 lines>...
              depends=ext.depends,
          )
        File "C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11929ne3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 457, in compile
          raise CompileError(msg)
      distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [101 lines of output]
      <string>:27: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\command.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\protoc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\any.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\api.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler\plugin.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler  
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\descriptor.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\duration.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\empty.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\field_mask.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\source_context.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\struct.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\timestamp.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\type.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\wrappers.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      running build_ext
      building 'grpc_tools._protoc_compiler' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\grpc_tools
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\base\internal
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\container\internal
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\crc
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\crc\internal
.
.
.
.
.
313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\objectivec
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\php
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\python
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\ruby
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\rust\accessors
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\io
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\third_party\protobuf\third_party\utf8_range
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DNOMINMAX=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\abseil-cpp -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -Ithird_party\protobuf\third_party\utf8_range "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include" "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\proto_parser_helper.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\proto_parser_helper.obj /std:c11 /MT
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      proto_parser_helper.cc
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DNOMINMAX=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\abseil-cpp -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -Ithird_party\protobuf\third_party\utf8_range "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include" "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.obj /std:c11 /MT
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      python_generator.cc
      third_party\protobuf\src\google/protobuf/map.h(689): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'google::protobuf::internal::map_index_t', possible loss of data
      third_party\protobuf\src\google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_sink.h(34): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(852): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data       
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data 
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DNOMINMAX=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\abseil-cpp -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -Ithird_party\protobuf\third_party\utf8_range "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include" "-IC:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.obj /std:c11 /MT
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      _protoc_compiler.cpp
      C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include\pyconfig.h(138): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
      C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include\pyconfig.h(138): note: 'MS_WIN64' previously declared on the command line
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(1190): warning C4996: 'Py_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.13
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(1191): warning C4996: 'Py_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.13
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(2307): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6401): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6413): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6425): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6464): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6476): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6493): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6536): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6548): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6560): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6572): error C3861: '_PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash': identifier not found
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8815): error C2660: '_PyLong_AsByteArray': function does not take 5 arguments
      C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include\cpython/longobject.h(111): note: see declaration of '_PyLong_AsByteArray'
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8815): note: while trying to match the argument list '(PyLongObject *, unsigned char *, size_t, int, bool)'    
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9049): error C2660: '_PyLong_AsByteArray': function does not take 5 arguments
      C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include\cpython/longobject.h(111): note: see declaration of '_PyLong_AsByteArray'
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9049): note: while trying to match the argument list '(PyLongObject *, unsigned char *, size_t, int, bool)'    
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9245): error C2660: '_PyLong_AsByteArray': function does not take 5 arguments
      C:\Users\AI Internist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include\cpython/longobject.h(111): note: see declaration of '_PyLong_AsByteArray'
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9245): note: while trying to match the argument list '(PyLongObject *, unsigned char *, size_t, int, bool)'    
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9833): error C3861: '_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue': identifier not found
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio-tools
Failed to build grpcio grpcio-tools
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (grpcio, grpcio-tools)

May I know what could be the cause of this? I have updated pip and setuptools to the latest version, as suggested here
pip 24.3.1
setuptools 75.6.0
I tried updating pip and setuptools. I also made sure my Python and C++ were installed with the latest versions. However, the same error still persisted.

Are you required to use Python 3.13 (free-threaded?) and grpcio[-tools] at 1.62.2 (18-April-2024) versus more current versions? If not, it would be useful to see whether your issue recurs by relaxing your requirement.

The errors mentioning _Py* arise if there is any problem with the Cython version. For grpcio v1.62.2, try adding cython>=0.29.8,<3.0.0rc1 in the requirements.txt file.
Also Python 3.13 support was added only in grpcio v1.66.2 and above. So please downgrade the Python version to something between 3.8 and 3.12.
If you wish to use Python 3.13 only, then opt for grpcio version 1.66.2+ and use cython>=3.0.0 in the requirements.txt file
